# How to change a sprite's image when a score changes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been creating an Xcode game in Swift using Sprite Kit. However, when I try to change the character's image when the high score goes above 40, it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
if  highScore >= 40{
    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "start")
}
```

Not too sure where I am going wrong but any advice would be much appreciated.

Here is the link to the source code:

https://github.com/skullamunger/Shootr-Master

Comment: FYI - you are not creating an "Xcode game". You are creating either an iOS game or a macOS game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only update the player texture:

```
if  highScore >= 40 {
    player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "start")
}
```

Here you are not creating a new sprite, you are just updating its texture.

Comment: thank you @YannickLoriot but that still doesn't work for some reason, the game runs but it still won't change the character. I'll upload the source code incase I am going wrong somewhere earlier

Comment: @skullamunger in your case the `highScore` variable is always equals to 0 inside this method that's why the sprite does not update its texture. It seems your highest score is stored in the `UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "highscore")`.

Comment: As I've said, instead of `if  highScore >= 40 {` use `if UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "highscore") >= 40 {`. But you should refactor your code to be more efficient.